# ActiveRecord adding rating range in migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
class AddRatingToBooks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    add_column :books, :rating, :integer
  end

  def down
    remove_column :books, :rating
end
```

I have the following snippet of code in my `db/migrate/`, I'm trying to add `ratings` to my `books` table, where it would be in a *range* from *0-100*, but I'm not sure how to add that here, all i could find was querying with ranges. I'm sure it's simple I'm just not there yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to specify the range of integer values in your migration file. The migration file is simply used to add the database column to store the rating. This is not the place to add validations.

You should use your `Book` model to specify a validation that ensures your `ratings` fall within a certain range. Something like this:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :rating, :inclusion => { :in => 0..100 }
end
```

I would highly recommend reading the Rails guides on both [migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) and [validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html).

Comment: yea, i figured i was in the wrong place. haha. Thanks.. i think that works.

Comment: Sure thing. Once you get it working, consider marking the answer as accepted if it answered your question :)

Comment: I haven'd made an answer as accepted before, how do i do that. by the way, i just tweeted the code and your answer did work well =) I'm excited. @JoelBrewer

Comment: Glad I could help! You should be able to click on the check mark, near where you would vote my answer up or down.

Comment: Oh haha, funny how we may miss things that are right on our face.

Answer (score 3):

Probably I'm too late with the answer. But it's possible to define validation on db level with Migration Validators project: https://github.com/vprokopchuk256/mv-core

As example, in your migration:

```rb
def change
  change_table :books do |t|
    t.integer :rating, inclusion: 0..100
  end
end
```

and then in your model:

```rb
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  enforce_migration_validations
end
```

As result your validation will be defined both in db ( as statement inside trigger or check constraint, depending on your db) and on your model

SQL ( PostgreSQL ):

```sql
=# insert into books(rating) values(10);
INSERT 0 1

=# insert into books(rating) values(200);
ERROR:  new row for relation "books" violates check constraint  "chk_mv_books_rating"
```

Rails console:

```rb
Book.new(title: 10).valid?
=> true

Book.new(title: 200).valid?
=> false
```